# Is it possible to invoke a lambda in code pipeline from a different account using CDK?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I am creating a pipeline through CloudFormation using CDK(TS), as part of this pipeline there is a step where I need to create a `LambdaInvokeAction` to call a lambda function with certain parameters. However this lambda function is from a different account, and when the template is generated, it is configuring codepipeline to find the lambda on the account is running.

This is the bit that tries to get the lambda:

```
const lambdaFunction = Function.fromFunctionAttributes(this, 'LambdaToUse', {
  functionArn: 'arn:aws:lambda:{region}:{external-account}:function:lambda-to-use',
  sameEnvironment: false,
  role: Role.fromArn(role-from-another-account),
});
```

This is the code that creates the invoke action:

```
    new LambdaInvokeAction({
      actionName: 'MyActionName',
      lambda: lambdaFunction,
      role: codePipelineExecutionRole,
      inputs: [buildOutput],
      userParameters: {
        // Parameters for the lambda function
      }
    });
```

I don't know if this is possible using CDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    stageName: 'InvokeLamabda',
    actions: [
    new codepipeline_actions.LambdaInvokeAction({
        actionName: 'InvokeAction',
        inputs: [buildOutput],
        userParameters: {
        // Parameters for the lambda function
        }
        role: iam.Role.fromRoleArn(this,'role',
        'arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/crossaccountcodepipeline',
        {mutable:false
        }),
        lambda: lambda.Function.fromFunctionAttributes(this, 'LambdaToInvoke', {
        functionArn: 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1234567890:function:myfunction',
        sameEnvironment: false
        }),
    }),
    ],
},
```

Make sure you have given the necessary permissions to the role to invoke the `lambda`

[Create a pipeline in CodePipeline that uses resources from another AWS account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create-cross-account.html)

Comment: Thanks, the permissions where fine, I found another solution

Comment: @LeoTorres just for. the community, can you mark this resolved or post your own, so we can resolve this post ?

Comment: @LeoTorres could you please tell us what is the other solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that I was trying to use `LambdaInvokeAction` from CDK, it seems it tries to find the lambda within the same account (I don't know if it can be configured not to do this). Creating a class from `Action` instead sorted my issue.